# Stripe subscription Id coming back undefined when querying by customer ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, undefined

My stripe customer ID is no longer querying the corresponding subscription ID from stripe and the results come back `undefined` so my customers can't cancel subscriptions.

I'd like to follow the [stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object?lang=node) but I can't get the subscription ID to return and I've found a couple examples on stack  that recommend the format as `customer.subscriptions.data[0]` but it's not working as intended (github autopilot also recommends this format).

I'm able to create new customers via the webhook so my connection and `stripeSecret` are working correctly but how do I fix my code to cancel a subscription using the customer ID:

**Controller function**

```
module.exports.cancelSubscription = async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
    if (!user) {
        req.flash('error', 'Cannot find that user');
        return res.redirect('/users');
    }

    const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(user.stripeId);

    // use customer id to get subscription id
    const subscriptionId = customer.subscriptions.data[0];

    // cancel subscription
    stripe.subscriptions.del(subscriptionId, { at_period_end: false });

    // update user subscription status in my database
    user.subscription.active = "cancelled";
    await user.save();
    req.flash('success', 'Subscription cancelled');
    res.redirect(`/users/${user._id}`);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`subscriptions`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-subscriptions) parameter in Customer object is not included by default and it's expandable by including it in [`expand`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) parameter. For example,

```
const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(cus_xxx, {
  expand: ['subscriptions'],
});

const subscriptions = customer.subscriptions.data;
```

Alternatively, you can also use List Subscriptions API with [`customer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list#list_subscriptions-customer) set to retrieve customer's subscriptions.

After the subscriptions are retrieved, you can then delete the subscription individually with [Cancel Subscription API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/cancel).

Comment: Thanks @yuting - I was using the wrong customer ID in my query (turns out I was creating two stripe customers during the user checkout process) and your code helped me troubleshoot that and works once I fix the process to only create one customer ID, then query subscriptions by said customer ID.